# How to compute $\frac{1 + a_1 \times \dots \times a_n}{b_1 \times \dots \times b_n}$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are secret?

Tags: secret-sharing

How can $n$ peers compute

$$\frac{1 + a_1 \times \dots \times a_n}{b_1 \times \dots \times b_n}$$

such that the pair of values $a_i$ and $b_i$ remains secret to the $i$-th peer?

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way of doing this using the [Paillier encryption scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) and $n$ honest-but-curious participants is as follows: a broker (such as participant $n$) generates a pair of secret primes $p$, $q$ and computes the public modulus $N=pq$. The modulus $N$ should be large enough that the broker is confident that $a_1\cdots a_n, b_1\cdots b_n<\sqrt N$. The broker should then form initial values $x_0=g\cdot r_0^N\mod{N^2}$ and $y_0=g\cdot s_0^N\mod{N^2}$ where $g=1+N$ and $r_0$ and $s_0$ are random values $0<r_0,s_0<n$. They then publish $N$, $g$, $r_0$ and $s_0$.

In order of participation, the $i$th peer computes $c_i=a_i/b_i\mod N$, $d_i=1/b_i\mod N$ and updates $x_i=x_{i-1}^{c_i}r_i^N\mod{N^2}$, $y_i=y_{i-1}^{d_i}s_i^N\mod{N^2}$ where again $r_i$ and $s_i$ are random values. Note that $x_i$ is a Paillier encryption of $a_1\cdots a_i/b_1\cdots b_i\mod N$ and $y_i$ is a Paillier encryption of $1/b_1\cdots b_i\mod N$. The intermediate values $x_i$ and $y_i$ should be kept private from the broker.

The $n$th peer can then compute $z=x_ny_n\mod{N^2}$ and pass this to the broker. Note that $z$ is a Paillier encryption of $(1+a_1\cdots a_n)/b_1\cdots b_n\mod N$. The broker then uses knowledge of the factors of $N$ to decrypt $z$ and recover $t=(1+a_1\cdots a_n)/b_1\cdots b_n\mod N$.

To recover $(1+a_1\cdots a_n)/b_1\cdots b_n\mod N$ as a rational number, the broker then uses a method akin to [Cornacchia's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornacchia%27s_algorithm) (i.e. the extended Euclidean algorithm, but stopping when the remainder is less than $\sqrt N$) to solve $t=t_1/t_2\mod N$ with $t_1,t_2<\sqrt N$.